# Can I create a report on the fly by passing a Json string?

Tags: c#, json, .net-5, fastreport

I have designed a report using the Community Designer, and, during design I used a JSON string as my data source. I understand I can point a different datasource when instantiating my report during runtime, but I couldn't find any information on whether I can pass a linearised JSON string to the report as a new datasource to prepare the report from. I'm using the open source version of FastReport.

The beginning of the report itself (I can post the rest of the file, but it's only the layout, and I'm not sure it pertains to this case):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report ScriptLanguage="CSharp" ReportInfo.Created="09/02/2021 15:21:14" ReportInfo.Modified="09/02/2021 16:09:54" ReportInfo.CreatorVersion="2021.3.28.0">
  <Dictionary>
    <JsonDataSourceConnection Name="Connection" ConnectionString="rijcmlqX8KZxth3MD10DNCoulBzT/ufTygbxgOYbNZVv0BNypI...uvs">
      <JsonTableDataSource Name="JSON" DataType="FastReport.Data.JsonConnection.JsonParser.JsonArray" Enabled="true" TableName="JSON">
```

Right now this is what I have:

```cs
    Report report = new Report();
    report.Load("reportTemplate.frx");
    report.Prepare();
    var reportExport = new FastReport.Export.Image.ImageExport();
    report.Export(reportExport, "report.jpeg");
```

By running this, I get the exact same report that I had using the Json string I provided when designing the report. On https://programmer.ink/think/using-fastreport-report-report-tool-to-generate-report-pdf-document.html they mention you can use `report.LoadFromString(string)` to pass either a Base64 or a UTF-8 Json string to be used as a datasource for the report. However, when I pass the linearised json:

```cs
Vehicle fullVehicleInfo = await _vehicleDataService.GetFullVehicleInfoAsNoTracking(_vehicleListingViewModel.SelectedVehicle);
    ReportObject ro = new(fullVehicleInfo, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1), DateTime.Now);
    var x = ro.ConvertToJson();
    Report report = new Report();
    report.Load("reportTemplate.frx");
    report.LoadFromString(x);
    report.Prepare();
    var reportExport = new FastReport.Export.Image.ImageExport();
    report.Export(reportExport, "report.jpeg");
```

The Json created from `ro.ConvertToJson` is the very same I pasted on the report creation wizard. Yet, I get a `The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.` exception, whereas if I convert that string to Base64 first and pass the encoded string, I get a `Cannot load the file. Unknown file format` exception.

In https://www.fast-report.com/en/blog/57/show/, they say I must "register" my application data, however, they are using a `List<JsonObject>`, while my report uses a single `JsonObject` with listed properties, so I don't think how that fits my situation.

I did try, though, passing a `List<ReportObject>` consisting of the single `ReportObject` and calling `report.RegisterData(z, "JSON")` (after removing the original datasource on the designer, but now I get a `The name "JSON" does not exist on the current context`, followed by the name of the field trying to access the property.

Just in case, this is an example of the JSON I'm using:

```json
{
    "DataInício": "02/08/2021",
    "DataFim": "02/09/2021",
    "Marca": "Renault",
    "Modelo": "Kwid Zen 1.0",
    "Placa": "TES-7E15",
    "Quilometragem": "1789,00 km",
    "PróximoLicenciamento": "08/2021",
    "ÚltimoAbastecimento": "25/08/2021",
    "ÚltimaManutenção": "28/08/2021",
    "ManutençãoJsons": [
        {
            "KM": "1687,0 km",
            "Custo": "R$ 50,00",
            "DataHora": "28/08/2021",
            "Motorista": "TESTE ARMANDO DE SALLES",
            "TipoReparo": "Preventivo",
            "TipoManutenção": "Revisão",
            "ÁreaManutenção": "Pneus"
        }
    ],
    "ViagemJsons": [
        {
            "Motorista": "TESTE ARMANDO DE SALLES",
            "KMInicial": "1569,0 km",
            "KMFinal": "1789,0 km",
            "Saída": "23/08/2021",
            "Entrada": "02/09/2021"
        }
    ],
    "AbastecimentoJsons": [
        {
            "KM": "1,0 km",
            "Motorista": "TESTE ARMANDO DE SALLES",
            "ValorTotal": "R$ 10,00",
            "Litragem": "10,0 l",
            "ValorPorLitro": "1,000 R$/l",
            "DataHora": "25/08/2021",
            "Posto": "carr",
            "Combustível": "Gasolina Aditivada",
            "FormaPagamento": "Dinheiro"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to directly pass a Json string as a datasource to the report?

Also, mind that creating a report *using the `ReportObject` and passing it as a business object works flawlessly*, but I still would like to know if I could pass it as a simple Json string.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it here is a sample code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RegisteredObjects.AddConnection(typeof(JsonDataSourceConnection));

    JsonDataSourceConnection jsonDataSourceConnection = new JsonDataSourceConnection();

    jsonDataSourceConnection.ConnectionString = "Json=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;JsonSchema=eyJ0eXBlIjoiYXJyYXkiLCJpdGVtcyI6eyJ0eXBlIjoib2JqZWN0IiwicHJvcGVydGllcyI6eyJNYW5hZ2VySWQiOnsidHlwZSI6Im51bWJlciJ9LCJEZXNjcmlwdGlvbiI6eyJ0eXBlIjoic3RyaW5nIn0sIkNvZGUiOnsidHlwZSI6InN0cmluZyJ9LCJDb3VudCI6eyJ0eXBlIjoic3RyaW5nIn0sIkhlYWRpbmciOnsidHlwZSI6InN0cmluZyJ9fX19;Encoding=utf-8";

    jsonDataSourceConnection.CreateAllTables();

    Report report = new Report();

    report.Dictionary.Connections.Add(jsonDataSourceConnection);

    report.Prepare();
    report.Design();
}
```

Comment: How was that Json string generated?

Comment: @ArturS. It's a base64 encoding of the JSON data.